# Existence of an ensemble of pure states for a prescribed density matrix

Tags: quantum-computation, quantum-information

[image]

I managed to prove (a), but am stuck at (b). Given a density matrix, I can't find a way to construct an ensemble of pure states for the matrix. I think I may have to diagonalize $\rho$.... Could anyone help me with (b)?

Comment: Any hermitian matrix is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues. Since you matrix is positive semi-definite, its eigenvalues are non-negative. Since the trace is $1$, the eigenvalues falls within $[0,1]$.